# Best Practice for Including JS (with PHP) in WordPress Functions file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm building a custom WordPress theme and have a quick question regarding WordPress and the Functions.php

I've got 500 lines of `jQuery` that run for a portion of my custom theme admin panel. The `jQuery` code is located inside of my `functions.php` file, called when the custom admin menu page is displayed.

Ideally, I would like to move the JavaScript out of the `functions.php` file and use wp_register_script + wp_enqueue_script, but I also have some php code mixed in with the script. See below:

```
//Function that Provides Options within the Menu Page
function quz_custom_theme_options(){
  global $quz_default_colors, $quz_default_fonts;

    ?>

   <style type="text/css">';

    <?php   include('admin-style.php'); ?>

   </style>';



<script type="text/javascript">
function asf_toggle_box(element)
{
  if (jQuery(element).next('.expandable').is(':visible') )
  {
    jQuery(element).next('.expandable').fadeOut('slow', function(){
      jQuery(element).val('+ Settings');
      jQuery(element).next('.expandable').find('.indicator').val('');  
    });
  } else {
    jQuery(element).next('.expandable').fadeIn('slow', function(){
      jQuery(element).val('- Settings');
      jQuery(element).next('.expandable').find('.indicator').val('visible');  
    });
  }
}
```

Example of PHP inside of js

```
function quz_reset_colors(t)
  {
    var theme_name = jQuery(t).attr('id').substr(6);
    var color_fields = jQuery(t).parent().find('div.color_admin_area').find('.color-input-wrap > input[type="text"]');
    // jQuery(color_fields).css('border', '1px solid red');
    // console.log(color_fields);
    var colors = new Array();
    <?php
    foreach ($quz_default_colors as $key => $value)
    {
      echo 'var ary = new Array(\'' . implode('\',\'', $value) . '\');' . "\r\n";
      echo 'colors[\'' . $key . '\'] = ary;' . "\r\n";
    }
    ?>
    jQuery(color_fields).each(function(index, elem){
      jQuery(elem).val(colors[theme_name][index]);    
    });
```

What is the best way to handle this? Should I just put all the **JS** in a separate php file and use `include('my_script.php');` Like I've done with the **CSS** in the above statement?

I have multiple ways of making this work, but I want to do it the BEST way. Thoughts?

Comment: wow that's though coding.. like what i'm doing also but this is much more confusing when going back to your codes to debugged especially having 500 lines... a praise you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do a small trick to do this in my [Easy Retweet WordPress Plugin](http://sudarmuthu.com/wordpress/easy-retweet).

```
// Enqueue the script
add_action('template_redirect', 'add_script');

function add_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('retweet', get_option('home') . '/?retweetjs');
}

add_action('init', 'deliver_js');

function deliver_js() {
    if ( array_key_exists('retweetjs', $_GET) ) {

        header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
        print_retweet_js($options);

        // die after printing js
        die();
    }
}

function print_retweet_js($options) {
     include_once('path/to/your/js/script.php');
}
```

Hope this is useful to you

Comment: Would appreciate if you accept this answer, if it solves your problem.

Comment: Sorry, new to the StackOverflow system. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
function theme_script() {
?>
    < script type="text / javascript" >
      here is your script
    < /script >
<?php
 wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_script_id', get_bloginfo('template_directory').'/js/theme_script.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
}
 add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'theme_script' );
```

Comment: Thats not going to work, look at the code, its full of PHP. It needs to be in a file with a .php extension to run it through the PHP interpreter first.