# Wordpress get_post_meta not working inside a .php file that is written for dynamic php?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, dynamic

I want to tie in jquery functions with post meta options, so I have created a PHP file with jQuery code inside the PHP tags.

```
      <?php
      echo "
           function dynamicAdjust() {
             jQuery('#main-home').css('margin-top', jQuery(window).height());       
           }
       ";
       ?>
```

Maybe there is a better way to create dynamic PHP (let me know if there is) with post meta options, but the jQuery here works fine, I enqueued in in my functions.php as a javascript file, and the jQuery funciton works fine.

The issue and the whole point of having the jQuery inside a PHP file is for users to turn options on/off so for example when I wrap the code up there in an if statement like so.

```
       <?php
         if(get_post_meta($post->ID, '_moon_full_static_area', true) == 'on'); {
            echo "
               function dynamicAdjust() {
               jQuery('#main-home').css('margin-top', jQuery(window).height());     
               }
             ";
            }
        ?>
```

This gives me this error **Fatal error**: Call to undefined function get_post_meta() in my dir..

Ok so according to the message its obvious that it does not see get_post_meta as a function, I know anything that has post_meta enabled is connected to the database, Im just not sure what else I need to do other than enqueue the script?? Any ideas?

PS.. [Best Practice for Including JS (with PHP) in WordPress Functions file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12739197/best-practice-for-including-js-with-php-in-wordpress-functions-file?rq=1) I came across this, is this what I am looking for?

Comment: Please, ask a new Question instead. If in doubt, take a look at the guides [About] and [help].

Comment: Ah Okay no problem... just didnt want to dilute this site with so many questions... I really appreciate the help though...

Comment: The site has **5.3 million** questions. Don't worry. Asking a new one is the right thing to do (after you've researched and tried by yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The standard way to pass PHP values to your Javascript files is through [**`wp_localize_script`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) .
[***See also***](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=wp_localize_script%20is:answer) *in WordPress Answers*.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'localize_script_so_17497763' );

function localize_script_so_17497763() 
{ 
    // Maybe check for `is_single()` or other Conditional Tag

    // Check post meta 
    global $post;
    $get_meta = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_moon_full_static_area', true );
    $meta_value = ( $get_meta == 'on' ) ? 'on' : 'off';

    // Build localization array to be passed
    $localize_array = array(
            'moon'    => $meta_value,
            'post_id' => $post->ID,
            'title'   => $post->post_title,
    );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my-file', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'my-file.js', array('jquery') );
    wp_localize_script( 'my-file', 'wplocal', $localize_array );
}
```

And then, in `my-file.js`:

```
console.log( wplocal.moon );
console.log( wplocal.post_id );
console.log( wplocal.title );
```

See: [What is the JavaScript equivalent of var_dump or print_r in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/603987/1287812)

Comment: This sounds about right, let me give it a crack and holler back here in a few! Thanks!!!

Comment: Ok Sweet the console log returned "on" value, it works... umm well would I use that in an if statement? like if(wplocal.moon){my JQuery here....}

Comment: Ill give that a crack.. but what would be the best way to pass multiple get_post_meta queries? just keep writing new arrays?

Comment: WOOHOO awesome dude, that worked and now I have witnessed the power of wp_localize_script... what about passing multiple queries though?

Comment: Shoot one more thing, how do I write if = true? how will it know 'on' = true and 'off' = false

Comment: Uou, nice to see you got the `localize` fever, it's pretty cool indeed :) You can make `$localize_array` as multidimensional as you like. Do all your queries and data grab and pass it in that var. And check [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/603987/1287812).

Comment: @MichaelJosephAubry, I've expanded the example.